# How to represent structure in a C like language in 3-address code?

Tags: compiler-construction, intermediate-language, intermediate-code

What is the three address code IR for a C code-snippet declaring a structure?

```
struct name{
char c;
int i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *Three Address Code* primarily works with assignments. You can represent only the assignments of the fields. All fields has an address.